# how to call a ajax function automatically after reloading the page

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsp, servlets

I have ajax function like this:

```
  $("#noOfFollowing").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url : 'Details',
            type : 'POST',
            data: "",
            success : function(msg) {
                $("#NOFOLLOWING").html(msg);

            }
        });

    });
```

and my html element is

```
  <u id ="noOfFollowing"></u><i id="NOFOLLOWING""></i>
```

i want to call the ajax function without clicking the html element. It should be called after every page reload. As soon as reload my web page this function should be called immediately without clicking separately. Here the url is a servlet. If some other alternative is there then please suggest them also.

Comment: And should it be called after first page loading? If so, you can simply use `$(document).ready();`

Answer (score 0):

You should put your Ajax call in this:

```
  $(document).ready(function (){

   $.ajax({
            url : 'Details',
            type : 'POST',
            data: "",
            success : function(msg) {
                $("#NOFOLLOWING").html(msg);

            }
        });
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
function get_data(){
$.ajax({
        url : 'Details',
        type : 'POST',
        data: "",
        success : function(msg) {
            $("#NOFOLLOWING").html(msg);        
        }
    }); 
}
```

HTML

```
<u id ="noOfFollowing" onclick="get_data()" ></u><i id="NOFOLLOWING""></i>
```

In Script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
get_data() //After page load this function called
});
```